# Date Conversion Problem

Tags: c#

i have Converted by code  Date Formate DD/MM/YYYY Locally but when Publish Application on Windows Server 2008 then Automatically display date in MM/DD/yyyy any body tell me what is Problem.. so Windows server 2008 display date in DD/MM/YYYY
Code is as Under which is not working

```
    System.IFormatProvider frmt = default(System.IFormatProvider);
    frmt = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    dtDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text,  frmt);
```

Comment: You say that you have a problems displaying dates in the good format, but in your code you're just parsing a date... There's something I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Date conversion (from string) using DateTime.Parse() has the nasty habbit of using the locale settings for the computer it is running.

A better way of converting is to run DateTime.TryParseExact() and explicitly supply your expected date formats.

Answer (score 1):

Your regional setting on server are probably different from your workstation; you could use `DateTime.ParseExact` to make your application culture safe

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the regional settings on the server are correct, and/or use an explicit format in the application if you want the date format to remain the same regardless of regional settings.

Comment: Code like this 


 System.IFormatProvider frmt = default(System.IFormatProvider);
        frmt = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);

       
        dtDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text,  frmt);